# How to continue the code if there is an error? Telethon

Tags: telegram, telethon

I have a simple program that allows user to join multiple chats/channel. User just inputs links of channels to join. But i have some troubles with channels that are private/not exist/deleted and etc. The program immideatly stops if can't join some chanel, but how can i make the program ignore these errors and continue its work until the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use python simple try and except :

```
try:
    #code
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Note that it's better to avoid writing bare `except`, as that will catch even keyboard interrupts.

Comment: Checkout errors at telethon docs.you can import error and except them